# JetBrains WebStorm/PhpStorm include path for SASS/SCSS

Tags: sass, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, node-sass

In project SCSS files I'm using relative paths to libraries:

```
@import "../node_modules/packagename/styles";
```

I would like to use include paths for them:

```
@import "packagename/styles";
```

It is fine for the compiler (node-sass) that was supplied with full path to `node_modules` with `includePaths` option.

However, IDE inspector throws

> Cannot resolve directory 'packagename'

Can it be fixed without turning off the inspection?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Marking `node_modules` as Resource Root (Mark directory as/Resource root) should solve the issue

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there no other known workaround? The project consists of two nested packages/repos, so there are two node_modules and two package.json. Nested one is for client part (where SCSS is used), parent one is for server and platform-independent part (which hosts client part and resource root). It is highly ineffective to split them into two independent projects currently.

Comment: hmm.. don't understand. and what is the problem marking the needed folder as resources root in such case?

Comment: You're right, there's no problem. Just didn't know that there may be more than one resource root. This works great, thank you.

Comment: Note: if you are trying to mark your node_modules/ as a Resource Root, and can't because it is already a Library Root... go into Preferences, Directories and you can choose both!  For some reason I can't right-click and mark it from the Project Navigator using 2017.3

Comment: I had trouble finding the "Preferences". The actual location @olore is talking about is File > Settings > Directories